# Cloudwatch event rule triggered by AWS ECR event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to setup CI/CD with AWS codepipeline and now I am stuck with pipeline autostart.
Looks like cloudwatch does not detect ECR events so does not start a pipeline.
Target and role configured correctly, but in access advisor for role I don`t see any role invocations.
Region us-west-2.

Here is event pattern that I use:

```
{
  "detail": {
    "eventName": [
      "PutImage"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "imageTag": [
        "service.develop.latest"
      ],
      "repositoryName": [
        "repository"
      ]
    }
  },
  "source": [
    "aws.ecr"
  ]
}
```

I can see PutImage events in cloudtrail but this rule does not work. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, magically this thing started to work.
Looks like an AWS bug as I did not fixed it somehow.